# selectmenuchange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdown select fields along with some text fields. One of the dropdown options is initially a text input readonly where some text comes from the server.

When the button **edit** is clicked, that text field changes to a dropdown based on the value coming from server (only 2 values are possible).

So the value currently selected in the dropdown is the one coming from server and other value is 2nd possible option.

Based on that selection, there is a 2nd select field that should enable. To achieve that I am using *selectmenuchange*.

However, it doesnt work in my case. Let me explain more with code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="protocolParIcons">
    <a href="#!" class="sbtooltip" title="Apply"><button id="applyButton" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check"></button></a>
    <a href="#!" class="sbtooltip" title="Cancel"><button id="cancelButton" class="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel"></button></a>
    <a href="#!" class="sbtooltip" title="Edit"><button id="editFields" class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></button></a>
</div>

<td valign="top">
        <label for="cfgMethod_0">Configuration Method</label>
        <input type="text" class="ipv4editable" name="cfgMethod_0" id="cfgMethod_0" readonly>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipVersion_0">IP Version</label>
        <select id="ipVersion_0">
            <option>IPv4</option>
            <option>IPv6</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

**JS**

```
$("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu({
        width:250,
        disabled:true
    });

    /*initialize buttons*/
    $("#editFields").button({
        disabled:false
    });

    /*disabling cancel and apply buttons by default*/
    $("#cancelButton").button({
        disabled:true
    });
    $("#applyButton").button({
        disabled:true
    });

 $(document).on("click","#editFields",function(){

            $("#editFields").button("option","disabled",true);
            $("#applyButton").button("option","disabled",false);
            $("#cancelButton").button("option","disabled",false);

                var connMode = $("#cfgMethod_0").val();

                if (connMode === 'DHCP') {
                    $("#cfgMethod_0").replaceWith("<select class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_0' name='cfgMethod_0'> <option selected>DHCP</option> <option>static</option></select>");
                } else {
                    $("#cfgMethod_0").replaceWith("<select class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_0' name='cfgMethod_0'> <option>DHCP</option> <option selected>static</option></select>");
                    $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",false);

                }

                $("#cfgMethod_0").selectmenu({
                    width: 250,
                    disabled: false
                });    

    $(document).on("click","#cancelButton",function(){
            $("input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true).css("border-color","");
            $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            $("#editFields").button("enable");
            $("#applyButton").button("disable");
            $("#cancelButton").button("disable");
            $("#cfgMethod_0").replaceWith("<input type='text' id='cfgMethod_0' name='cfgMethod_0' class='ipv4editable' readonly>");
            }           

    });

    $(document).on("click","#applyButton",function(){
            $("input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true).css("border-color","");
            $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            $("#editFields").button("enable");
            $("#applyButton").button("disable");
            $("#cancelButton").button("disable");

            $("#cfgMethod_0").replaceWith("<input type='text' name='cfgMethod_0' class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_0' readonly>");
    });

    /*this is the part that should have done the expected */
    $("#cfgMethod_0").on("selectmenuchange",function(){
        if($("#cfgMethod_0 :selected").text() === "static") {
            console.log("*********************"+$("#cfgMethod_0 :selected").text());
            $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",false);

            $('.ipv4editable').prop("readonly",false);
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","red");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",false);
        }
        else{
            console.log("else *********************"+$("#cfgMethod_0 :selected").val());
            $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);

            /*disable ipv4 section */
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("readonly",true);
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",true);

            /*disable ipv4 section */
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("readonly",true);
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    }).trigger('selectmenuchange');
```

In the console, somehow I get the value as undefined when i try to print select option for **cfgMethod_0** id which is within the selectmenu code.

I feel somehow with *replacewith* statements it is unable to know that the input text is turning out to be a select menu later.

I have tried placing the *selectmenuchange* code on several places but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After really thinking a lot, I tried to do just what I did with other button events. I used :-

```
$(document).on("selectmenuchange","#cfgMethod_0",function(){
        /*all the same code*/
    }).trigger('selectmenuchange');
```

Thats it. It seems otherwise , it loses track the id which is first of type text and then changes to select and vice versa.